# Recover AES IV if only key and plaintexts are known

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

If I decrypt a ciphertext in AES-CBC mode and the decrypted plaintext of the first block does not match the original known plaintext, it is clear that the IV used for decryption does not match the IV used during encryption.

Neither of the IVs used for encryption or decryption is known.

If I knew the ciphertext, I could do the following to find the IV used during encryption (tried it and it works):

1. Set IV=0
2. x = decrypt(ciphertext, IV)
3. originalIV = x xor originalPlaintext

Is there a way to recover the IV that was used in the encryption, given I know the original plaintext (before encryption), the wrong plaintext after decryption and the key?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about cryptography rather than programming. The right forum is crypto.stackexchange.com, and this would be a good question there.

Comment: @ArtjomB. His question s how to do this without ciphertext. Pokey: It´s impossible. The IV is in no relation to plaintext and key alone, it can be any possibel value.

Comment: thanks @deviantfan that seems to be correct. I could just verify it, since i end up with 2 unknowns in just 1 equation. so its not solvable.

Comment: You can just execute step 3, can't you? You would not even need the key.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes no, step 3 requires x which is obtained from step 2 which in turn requires a key and ciphertext. But the ciphertext is unknown.

Comment: "given I know the original plaintext (before encryption), the wrong plaintext after decryption and the key" - isn't x the "wrong plaintext"?

Comment: No it isnt, it is more like:
x = originalPlaintext xor originalIV

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understood the question: this is absolutely possible, and absolutely off topic.  Notice you shouldn't ask crypto questions on a programmer forum or you'll get all sorts of wrong answers.

Let `D` be your cipher decryption function.  If you have the known plaintext `PT`, the key `K` and ciphertext from CBC mode `CT` then you can recover the first `IV` used for encryption via:

```
IV0 = D(CT0) ^ PT0
```

In your steps I assume by `decrypt` you mean CBC mode.  This works because for a single block `CBC_Decrypt(K,IV=0,CT) == D(K,CT)`.